# An instance of IBUITableViewCellContentView could not be decoded error ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, compiler-errors, instance, decode

[image: Error:]

Hi all, when I try to compile my iOS app, I get the error saying that the .xib could not be opened. I've looked around online and couldn't find anything that worked. Any suggestions? Or should I just recreate the xib?

Thanks in Advance

EDIT: I can now compile the app by removing the .xib from the copy bundle resources, but during runtime i get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/CE59BF1F-1A6D-46F9-8787-E957FDA6F788/customtablecelltest.app> (loaded)' with name 'CustomTableCell''
```

I'm pretty sure the .xib has to be in copy bundle resources, so I put it back. Any fixes for the original problem

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this is for simulator v7.0.  Did you start the project pre-7.0?  I just had this problem and removed the simulator project folder and rebuilt (if you're paranoid, just rename/mv it).

Try renaming or moving your simulator project folder and rebuilding.  Yours appears to be:
/Users/username/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/CE59BF1F-1A6D-46F9-8787-E957FDA6F788/customtablecelltest.app

Comment: I ended up recovering the .xib from a earlier commit and using that, but I guess your solution would work too.

Answer (score 0):

One of two things is wrong:

1) you deliberately specified in your XIB that the cell's class is named IBUITableViewCellContentView (in the "identity inspector" panel, under "custom class") and there is no such class in your project (or it exists but is not added to the target you are compiling).

2) you accidentally specified in your XIB that the cell's class is named IBUITableViewCellContentView and you meant something else.

Did you create a custom class for your cell?  You should be able to correct this by either adding that class to your target and/or updating the custom class name in your XIB.

Comment: there is a custom class for the cell. the custom class is in build is in compile sources.

Comment: also i cant change the custom class for the xib because the xib cannot be opened, so it is "no selection"

Comment: You definitely need your XIB in the target if you're going to use it.  Did you edit the XIB directly (eg: in a text editor) and corrupt it?  Perhaps restore it from an earlier version (or re-create it).  Then go to the identity inspector panel, pick the "custom class" field and put in the name of your Objective-C class which the OS should use to manage the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Do as follows

- Open the project in Xcode 6,
- and in the Project Navigator select your XIB.
- Click on Identity and Type and change the Interface Builder Document
  to Opens in: Default (6.2). While you’re there you change the Builds
  For setting as well.

for details [link](http://www.it-guy.com/2015/09/fix-for-ibuiscreenmetrics-could-not-be-decoded/)